# Maximum Likelihood and the Empirical Distribution

Tags: maximum-likelihood, uniform-distribution, kullback-leibler

I am reading [Goodfellow et al. "Deep Learning" book (2016)](https://www.deeplearningbook.org/). In chapter 5, where they are explaining Maximum Likelihood, they imply the empirical distribution $\hat p_{data}$ as a uniform distribution in which each data point has a chance of $1/m$ where we have $m$ data points. As we do not know the true underlying distribution from which our i.i.d observations have been drawn, we must find model parameters $\theta$ that approximates $\hat p_{data}$ the best (a.k.a minimizes the divergence between these two distributions).
What I am wondering about is that why we assume that the empirical distribution is uniform? isn't this very limiting? the underlying distribution might be any distribution and I do not understand why to make such an assumption and proceed with it. I appreciate any hints on the intuition behind this.

Comment: One is not assuming the underlying distribution is Uniform, but uses the observations to _approximate it_, with no reason to weight one observation more than another. The more points in the sample, the more in the support of the empirical distribution. The theoretical justification is the [Glivenko-Cantelli  theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glivenko%E2%80%93Cantelli_theorem).

Comment: Note also that the empirical distribution can be interpreted as a non-parametric MLE.